# Changing NSNumber nested in NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not to be able to change a NSNumber within a NSMutableDictionary. The 'Before' NSLog prints but then crashes when I change the number.

As you can see the class is of type NSNumber and therefore I should be able to change the number with the class method 'numberWithIn'. However, I  get the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance." Which is strange because if the method didn't exist, the if statement would not work? Thoughts? Have I just missed something strange?

Data is an NSMutableArray and within are NSMutableDictionaries from json data. Data has been initialised.

```
  if([[Data[i] objectForKey:@"Pop"] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
        NSLog(@"Before: %@",[Data[i] objectForKey:@"Pop"]);

        [[Data[i] objectForKey:@"Pop"] numberWithInt:5];
        NSLog(@"After: %@",[Data[i] objectForKey:@"Pop"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if([[Data[i] objectForKey:@"Pop"] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
    NSLog(@"Before: %@",[Data[i] objectForKey:@"Pop"]);

    [[Data[i] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:@"Pop"];
    NSLog(@"After: %@",[Data[i] objectForKey:@"Pop"]);
}
```

should work.
You didnt properly set a new NSNumber object.

Answer (score 1):

`[Data[i] objectForKey:@"Pop"]` just access an element of your dictionary. If you want to change it you need a method that does so: `[Data[i] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:@"Pop]` or more concisely `[Data[i] setObject:@5 forKey:@"Pop"]`. Did you know you can also access dictionary elements now like so: Data[i][@"Pop"]...

Answer (score 0):

`+(NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)value` is a class method to create a new `NSNumber`. You cannot call it on an instance of `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of those function :

```
[dataArray setObject:yourObject forKey:@"Pop"];

[dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:theIndextoChange withObject:yourObject];
```